# Android: I am using a mapview and ItemizedOverlay. I am ploting a drawable on that, it does not shows correct place

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview, android-maps

Android: I am using a mapview and ItemizedOverlay. I am ploting a drawable on that, it does not shows correct place. It shows correct position on map when full zoom in but when it is zoom out the marker is moving from correct position. 
Can any one know the solution. Should I need to do something in draw of ItemizedOverlay.?

Does anyone knows the solution. Please help me.

regards,
dharma

Comment: Post your code and screenshots for both scenario.